# How can I have only a * notation wpf grid column resize when the containing control is resized and not clip other columns?

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I have a grid with certain column settings:

```
<Grid>

    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".25*" MinWidth="200"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="240" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
....Omitting content to keep this simple....
</grid>
```

When I resize the width of the containing control, the center column resizes as expected, to a point. Then it will start to clip the third column for no apparent reason (there's still room for the center column to shrink). How can I force WPF to only resize the center column, and only clip the third column if the center column's width is at 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:

Try using a `MultiValueConverter` to minimize the `MaxWidth` of the second column to the available space in the grid. The code below should do the trick:

**Xaml:**

```
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Name="col1" Width=".25*" MinWidth="200"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Name="col2" Width="*">
            <ColumnDefinition.MaxWidth>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource GridWidthConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName="col1" Path="MinWidth"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="col3" Path="Width"/>
                    <Binding ElementName="Control" Path="ActualWidth"/>
                </MultiBinding>
            </ColumnDefinition.MaxWidth>
        </ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Name="col3" Width="240" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

**Converter:**

```
public class GridWidthConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    #region IMultiValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object[] values, System.Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var col1 = System.Convert.ToDouble(values[0]);
        var col2 = System.Convert.ToDouble(((GridLength)values[1]).Value);
        var control = System.Convert.ToDouble(values[2]);

        var maxWidth = control - (col1 + col2);

        return maxWidth > 0 ? maxWidth : 0;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, System.Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return null;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

You may want to add some error checking to the converter but it should give you the idea.

Comment: There is content in column 2. I want column 2 to be as large as possible without causing clipping on column 3. Auto for column 2 is not what I want I'm afraid.

Comment: I have just edited my answer but I see you already have a solution!

Comment: I accepted your answer as I thought about it and realized that you actually answered my original question, and I did not.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring out the problem. Richard E led me in the right direction. Apparently the act of setting a * notation on a column and a minimum width caused the behavior I was experiencing. Specifically, when column 1 stopped shrinking due to hitting the minimum width, column 2 only continued to shrink at a rate that it would have if column 1 continued to shrink as well. This version of the xaml works correctly:

```
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="240" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

I don't know if the behavior I encountered was intentional or not.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I can't accept my own answer yet...and  I can't upvote Richard E yet. I will do so when I can.

Comment: Just a quick note, which may be of no significance in your scenario, but removing the .25* on the first column will prevent it from widening when the grid grows. The width relationship with column 2 will now be lost.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I decided that the fixed width was more important in this case. It also worked if I kept the .25* and dropped the MinWidth.